# Explorer stops responding when opening Git Bash

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, git, msysgit

When I open Git Bash from the Explorer context menu, Explorer stops responding, regardless whether the folder is a Git folder. Immediately when I close Git Bash, Explorer starts to respond again.

My system is running Windows 7 Professional x64 and the Git version is 1.9.0.msysgit.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this? Here is a gif describing the problem: [image]

Comment: create a dump of the Explorer, open the dump in WinDbg and run **!analyze -v -hang**. Copy & paste the Windbg output to pastebin and post a link here

Comment: @magicandre1981 and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use Taskmgr or ProcessExplorer to generate the dump. Windbg is part of the WinSDK (Debugging Tools)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it is a problem with the git-cheetah extension with git 1.9.0.

https://github.com/msysgit/Git-Cheetah/commit/e7af79862b136efb414ac545f282939e2d290e3e

> A recent change made for FarManager makes Git Cheetah capture
>   stderr/stdout even when we are not interested in it, to avoid cluttering
>   FarManager's precious console. Due to this workaround, Git Bash makes the
>   Explorer -- Git Cheetah's primary intended consumer -- hang.

It looks like the fix has been commited to the codebase but as to when it will appear in the git update I have no idea!

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm that uninstalling / reinstalling with:

```
[x] Windows Explorer integration
   (*) Simple context menu (Registry based)
      [x] Git Bash Here
      [x] Git GUI Here
   ( ) Advanced context menu (git-cheetah plug-in)
```

...solved the problem for me under Windows 8.1 while keeping the functionality I needed. Thanks to Justin for the real answer; sorry I don't have the rep yet to make this just a comment.

Comment: Confirmed, using simple context menu (registry-based) instead of advanced context menu (git-cheetah plugin), works.